# How can I create an array in python using a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have an array set out like this:

```
['age', 'height', 'weight']
```

and I need to "fill" the array with values from a list which contains objects with the values age, height and weight.

For example:

```
for value in list:
    age = value.age
    height = value.height
    weight = value.weight
    "[{}, {}m, {}lb]".format(age, height, weight)
```

and I would like to get the desired output:

```
[21, 1.77m, 160lb]
[25, 1.56m, 145lb]
```

etc for each object in the list.

So the final output would end up being like this:

```
['age', 'height', 'weight']
[21, 1.77m, 160lb]
[25, 1.56m, 145lb]
```

Comment: Thats what I have tried so far with the for loop, the value.age, etc works for getting the value but I can't get it to "fill" the containers with the values, without it getting rid of the previous container

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. What does "list" look like when you print it?

Comment: Also, what are you actually doing with this statement: `"[{}, {}m, {}lb]".format(age, height, weight)`? You're calculating the format, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it (assigning it to a variable, printing it to screen, etc.).

Comment: Well it isn't being used to print it to the screen but I need to insert it into a html code, so I need the array to be a string that can then be implemented into the html code as a multiline string, if that makes sense.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to start with an empty string before the `for` loop, and append to it on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand then you are looking for:

```
head = [['age', 'height', 'weight']]
for obj in obj_list: # overriding built-in list is a bad idea
    head += [obj.age, obj.height, obj.weight]
```

What will give you one array filled up with rest of the data:

```
[['age', 'height', 'weight'], 
 [21, 1.77m, 160lb], 
 [25, 1.56m, 145lb]]
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string like this:

```
In [5]: a, h, w = 10, 1.70, 200

In [7]: print "[%d, %.2fm, %dlb]" % (a, h, w)
------> print("[%d, %.2fm, %dlb]" % (a, h, w))
[10, 1.70m, 200lb]
```

Note that combining these values with string suffixes converts the elements to strings, which may or may not be good.